# Authentication using MVVM in WPF/SQlite

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, mvvm, authentication

I am developing a WPF Desktop Application, using Visual Studio 2017, and targeting DotNet 4.0. This time, I am focusing on the MVVM Approach.

During the first stage of development, I need to create a Login page, that will authenticate the user from SQLite DB. For SQLite I am using System.Data.Sqlite and SQLiteConnection.

This is what I have planned so far:

**Views:** LoginView

**ViewModel:** LoginViewModel

**Model:** Users, Authentication

Users Class Library basically holds the Username, Password, Access Level etc. Object of Users will be created in the LoginViewModel, and will bind with the LoginView Textbox.

On Command of Button Click (using RelayCommand), ViewModel will pass the LoginInfo to Authentication class, which will then use an ApplicationDatabases Class, which in turn will use SQLiteHelper Class to get Data from the DB.

Other then these files, there are some other files such as Relay Command, ViewModelBase (implementing INPC).

I have two Questions.

1. Whether this approach is right or not ?
2. Authentication Class Library will be considered as a Model or a ViewModel ? and should I implement INotifyPropertyChanged in Authentication or Not ?

Comment: You should start from the beginning. Learn what is Class Library - it's not the same as Class. Read about INotifyPropertyChanged when it is used and why. And...google...here is the search result: [Easy login example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Easy-WPF-Login-Navigate-7a8d34a0/sourcecode?fileId=110632&pathId=563994747)

Comment: I have studied this Example, but I am a little bit confused on the existence of AuthenticationViewModel. How can AuthenticationViewModel exist when there is no directly related Authentication View ? There is only LoginView in this Example which is related to LoginViewModel.